# change the color of Highmap

Tags: css, highcharts, highmaps

I'm working on with Highmaps and this is the one I use :

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-ranges

In this map the colors for different countries goes from white to blue I want to change that to "Red to Blue" gradient like in this css example :

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green, blue); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify colors in the `colorAxis` object.

```
colorAxis: {
  dataClasses: [{
    to: 3,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    from: 3,
    to: 10,
    color: "yellow"
  }, {
    from: 10,
    to: 30,
    color: "green"
  }, {
    from: 30,
    to: 100,
    color: "blue"
  }, {
    from: 100,
    to: 300,
    color: "pink"
  }, {
    from: 300,
    to: 1000,
    color: "purple"
  }, {
    from: 1000,
    color: "black"
  }]
},
```

Hex values like `#FF0000` work as well.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8wcntpcz/

EDIT:
Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.dataClasses